# Randomly choose which group values to include in GROUP BY

Tags: sql, aggregation

I have a fairly large table, so that I'd like to do a group by over the entire table across users, but only return data for 10% of the users, sampled randomly. I know how to sample rows uniformly, but is there a 1-step way to randomly decide which users to include in a group by on the user field?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe could you order the results of the select clause randomly like this

```
SELECT TOP x *
FROM table_name
ORDER BY newid()
```